# Adding an input button to the end of a row created using for loop with custom function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently learning php right now. I have been trying to create a to-do app in which I add tasks to a SQL database using PDO. I have set up a table to display the task but I would like to add a button at the end of each row.

```
<?php

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Id</th><th>Task</th><th>Time entered</tr></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname ="todolist";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $task = $_POST['task'];
    //Create Record
    $sql = "INSERT INTO todoapp (task) VALUES ('$task')";
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    echo "New record is created and the last inserted ID is: ".$last_id;



    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM todoapp");
    $stmt->execute();


    $result= $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v){
       echo $v;
        }

} 


$pdo = null;
?>
```

Comment: it seems that your code is not complete. It is just making a table header only for now. Can you add your complete code?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.